# I've this problem when I start npm: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

when I do npm start it gaves me this error (it's Italian but you can use google translate):

```
npm start

> codeeditor@1.0.0 start D:\CodeEditor
> electron .

"electron" non ▒ riconosciuto come comando interno o esterno,
 un programma eseguibile o un file batch.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! codeeditor@1.0.0 start: `electron .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the codeeditor@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Giovanni\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-22T14_13_45_030Z-debug.log
```

thank you for help ;)

Comment: A more elaborate question would be appreciated,as to what you have tried , what you started .

Comment: Looks like `electron` is not available. Have you tried to install it globally `npm install -g electron` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use `npm init` to initialize `package.json` .Then use `npm i electron` for installing electron. Then try `npm start`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked, sorry it's my first time with it

Comment: Also make sure when you download anything from github etc. to use `npm i` for installing all dependencies before starting the application.(which can be seen in `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

Simplest the answer,
Install electron first and then run.

```
npm install electron
```

Also make sure you're not using gitbash for running the npm run.